# Usage of getCount(), getItem(), getItemId() class extending ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I'm a newbie to `Adapter`. So to learn more about how to implement `Adapter` I was going through various examples in SO and some other blogs. I found that many define `getCount()`, `getItem()`, `getItemId()` in a custom Adapter class extending `ArrayAdapter` and doesn't even use those functions. I understand that in a custom class extending 'BaseAdapter', we have to override `getCount()`, `getItem()`, `getItemId()` to get things done.

So to my question, Do I have to define these functions in a custom Adapter class while extending `ArrayAdapter`?

**Note** : What really surprised me was that when I implemented a custom `Spinner` using a custom Adapter extending `ArrayAdapter` without defining these functions, there seems no problem and everything worked fine. I'm really confused whether I have done it wrong.

Comment: @people who are down voting. Please also comment the reason for down voting. Thanks.

Comment: Just check the sources of `ArrayAdapter` and see whether those methods are already implemented, and in case you don't want to change the implementation - don't override them in your class.

Comment: `public T getItem(int position) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }` is all I can see. Should I assume that without giving `@Override` annotation we can override getItem() in custom Adapter ?

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java

Comment: @Egor is this correct ? Because 'getItem()' is defined in 'ArrayAdapter' it's not necessary to override it in our custom Adapter extending ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @Egor Thanks. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to define `getCount()`, `getItem()`, `getItemId()` while creating a custom Adapter extending `ArrayAdapter`. It is not necessary, as in the [definition](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) of `ArrayAdapter` these functions are overridden. But if we need to override these functions and provide our own definition, we can do that and there is no problem at all.

Thanks [Egor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543539/egor) for guiding me to the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Those methods are used internally when you "get your item". put your logic to fill your data in your "getView" method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?